# Why 'val arr: Int => Int = Array(1,2,3)' is allowed in scala

Tags: scala

With the following code:

```
object Foo {
  val arr: Int => Int = Array(1,2,3)  
}
```

We can call `Foo.arr(1)`, then get `2`. However, `arr` in object `Foo` should be a `Function`. The `arr` is an instance of Class `WrappedArray$ofInt`, which is obviously not a `Function`.
I guess maybe the reason is `WrappedArray$ofInt`implements `apply(i: Int)`, because the call `Array(1,2,3)(1)` will be translated into `Array(1,2,3).apply(1)`. But the following code would be error:

```
class Bar {
  def apply(i: Int): Int = {
    Array(1,2,3)(i)
  }
}
object Foo {
  val arr: Int => Int = new Bar()  //Type mismatch: 
                                   //    Required: Int => Int 
                                   //    Found: Bar
}
```

Now, why `val arr: Int => Int = Array(1,2,3)` is allowed in scala?

Comment: Usually, you will find `apply` in a companion object i.e.  in `object` instead of `class` and `val arr: Int => Int = Bar.apply` will work

Comment: The reason `Bar.apply` will work is `apply` is a function defined as `Int => Int`. The confusion is why Array(1,2,3) could be taken as `Int => Int`

Comment: `Int => Int` is equivalent to `Function1[Int, Int]` and it seems that some Arrays type (ArrayBuffer, ArraySeq ... and other collections) implements `Function1` (IDEA would list the implementations of `Function1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **REPL** is an amazing tool to explore these kinds of situations.

So, let's start with the code:

```scala
val arr: Int => Int = Array(1,2,3)
```

In **Scala** the only way this would work is if `Array[Int] <: Int => Int` or if there would be an implicit conversion from `Array[Int]` into something that is a subtype of `Int => Int`

We can check that the first one is not the case quite easily:

```scala
implicitly[Array[Int] <:< Int => Int]}
```

Which produces:

> error: No implicit view available from Array[Int] <:< Int => Int.

Thus, it has to be the second one; and we may also confirm it doing:

```scala
implicitly[Array[Int] => (Int => Int)]
// val res: Array[Int] => (Int => Int) = $Lambda$1165/0x00000008406ff040@4dac40b
```

BTW, if we paste the original line in the **REPL** we get the following output:

```scala
val foo: Int => Int = Array(1,2,3)
// val foo: Int => Int = ArraySeq(1, 2, 3)
```

So we can already see that the conversion took place and that the result is an `ArraySeq[Int]` *(and if you check the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ArraySeq.html) you can see that class does indeed inherit `Int => Int`)*.

---

If you want to dive even deeper you can use `reify`

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

reify { val foo: Int => Int = Array(1,2,3) }
```

Which produces the following output:

```scala
val res: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] =
Expr[Unit]({
  val foo: Function1[Int, Int] = Predef.wrapIntArray(Array.apply(1, 2, 3));
  ()
})
```

And following the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html?search=ArrayS#wrapIntArray(xs:Array%5BInt%5D):scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.ofInt) again we can see that it indeed returns an [`ArraySeq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq$$ofInt.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have taken several hours to understand it. Now, I admit that there is an implicit transformation from `Array[Int]` to `Int => Int`. But where is the place the transformation happens, maybe this is another question. 

Comment: Which one is the class/trait related to `Function[Int, Int]`? I have checked the link you mentioned: `sealed abstract class ArraySeq[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with IndexedSeq[A] with IndexedSeqOps[A, ArraySeq, ArraySeq[A]] with StrictOptimizedSeqOps[A, ArraySeq, ArraySeq[A]] with EvidenceIterableFactoryDefaults[A, ArraySeq, ClassTag] with Serializable`

Comment: I have asked another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016392/where-is-the-place-that-arrayint-is-implicitly-transformed-into-int-int). Look forward for your answer.