# Where is the place that 'Array[Int]' is implicitly converted to 'Int => Int' in scala?

Tags: scala

It is a question followed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000384/why-val-arr-int-int-array1-2-3-is-allowed-in-scala).
Now we have proved that `Array[Int]` could be implicitly converted into `Int => Int`, but **where** is the place that happens? 
Obviously, `Int => Int` is a Function:

```
scala> var fun = (i: Int) => Array(1,2,3)(i)
fun: Int => Int = <function1>
```

And `Array[Int]` is a class:

```
scala> var arr = Array(1,2,3)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

But `arr` can be assigned to `fun`:

```
scala> fun = arr
fun: Int => Int = WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)
```

Conversely, it will not work:

```
scala> arr = fun
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: Array[Int]
       arr = fun
             ^
```

Now, Where is the place that **implicit** conversion happens?

Comment: It happens at the assignment. It will coerce arr to the same type as fun so it can do assignment. It is the same as `fun = arr : (Int => Int)`

Comment: Perhaps you do not understand this question. Have you read that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000384/why-val-arr-int-int-array1-2-3-is-allowed-in-scala)? Please explain why `new Bar()` in that question can not be transformed to `Int => Int`

Comment: By looking at the answers you accepted, it appears you are asking where the implicit conversion functions are defined, not where the conversion happens. Maybe ask the question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but where is the place that happens?

Implicit conversions happen when necessary, in this case in the assignment itself.

Look at my `reify` block in my other answer:

```scala
val foo: Function1[Int, Int] = Predef.wrapIntArray(Array.apply(1, 2, 3));
```

That is the conversion right there, calling the method: `wrapIntArray` in the `Predef` object.

> Obviously, Int => Int is a Function:
> And Array[Int] is a class:
> But arr can be assigned to fun:
> Conversely, it will not work:

It seems you don't know / understand that in **Scala** `functions` are also `objects` *(almost everything in **Scala** is an `object`, anything that is a value will be an `object`)*.

So we can't directly assign an `Array[Int]` to a value that should be an `Int => Int`; because `Array[Int]` is not a subtype of `Int => Int` *(as shown in my previous answer)*.
But we can convert an `Array[Int]` into an `ArraySeq[Int]` which is a subtype of an `Int => Int` and thus we can do the assignment.

The opposite won't work because an `Int => Int` is not an `Array[Int]` nor a `ArraySeq[Int]`
Note this is just basic subtyping, a `Dog` is a subtype of `Pet` but a `Pet` is NOT a subtype of `Dog`

> Which one is the class/trait related to Function[Int, Int]? I have checked the link you mentioned: sealed abstract class ArraySeq[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with IndexedSeq[A] with IndexedSeqOps[A, ArraySeq, ArraySeq[A]] with StrictOptimizedSeqOps[A, ArraySeq, ArraySeq[A]] with EvidenceIterableFactoryDefaults[A, ArraySeq, ClassTag] with Serializable

Those are the classes / traits `ArraySeq` directly extends, in the **Scaladoc** link there is a button to see all supper types ad in those you will see `(Int) => A`

---

### Edit

> The last question is which super type does the (Int) => A come from? There are too many types ArraySeq extended.

You need to traverse the hierarchy:

1. immutable.ArraySeq extends immutable.AbstractSeq
2. immutable.AbstractSeq extends immutable.Seq
3. immutable.Seq extends collection.Seq
4. collection.Seq extends PartialFunction[Int, A]
5. PartialFunction[Int, A] extends Function1[Int, A]

Comment: Thank you again for your amazing answer. I have found `(Int) => A` in **Linear Supertypes** in the [Scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ArraySeq.html). The last question is which super type does the `(Int) => A` come from? There are too many types ArraySeq extended.

Comment: I have found the right type: `trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B`. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: @Han check the edit

Answer (score 5):

Since you have [`WrappedArray`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html) I'm guessing you have Scala 2.12 or earlier - Scala 2.13 has [`ArrayOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/ArrayOps.html).

There is an implicit conversion (actually [a whole family o conversions](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$.html#genericWrapArray%5BT%5D(xs:Array%5BT%5D):scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray%5BT%5D)) from `Array` to `WrappedArray`. So you have an implicit conversion from `Array[T]` to `WrappedArray[T]`.

Now, `WrappedArray` implements all sorts of Scala's collection traits. One of them is [`Seq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/Seq.html) implementing `PartialFunction` (which in turn extends `Function`). That means that all of collections in Scala are functions from some key (`Int` in case of sequences, possibly something else in case of `Map`s). This includes `WrappedArray`.

So your conversion to `WrappedArray` automatically turns an `Array[T]` into a (subtype of a) function `Int => T`.

As a matter of the fact, this is a reason why you should avoid putting any collection (or things implicitly convertible to collections like `Array` before 2.13) into implicit scope: a collection in implicit scope automatically becomes implicit conversion itself. This problem was solved only in Scala 3 where implicit conversions became [a separate subtype of `Function` interface](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/conversions.html).

Comment: I am sorry that i can mark only one answer as the right answer. Your answer is absolutely right for my question. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign `Array(1)` to a `val` of type `Int => Int`, the implicit conversion `scala.LowPriorityImplicits#wrapIntArray` is called.

It wraps the `Array` into `ArraySeq` and the later implements `Function1` or `Int => Int`